# Getting [invalid_id_token] Missing (required) ID Token in Token Response for Client Registration: github

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm using SpringBoot and Oauth2 to authenticate on my application, using github for now.
If I use the scope oidc on application.properties the process works fine and github is used for he login.

My issue is that I want/need to use scope openid to get the id_token. When I change my application.properties to

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.scope=openid
```

I start getting this error as response from login:

```
[invalid_id_token] Missing (required) ID Token in Token Response for Client Registration: github
```

I still get the `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/github?code=ABC&state=CDE` but right after that, the error shows up.

My security class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .and()
    .oauth2Login()
    ;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("springuser").password(passwordEncoder().encode("spring123")).roles("USER")
    .and()
    .withUser("springadmin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin123"))
    .roles("ADMIN", "USER");
    }
```

Any clue on what I should look to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.scope=openid
```

activates OpenID Connect authentication, that's built on top of Oauth2.
But that's no longer just Oauth2, as it requires that token.
If Oauth2 is what you want, just remove the above line.

Yes it's just confusing, and that's probably why folks avoid OIDC.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

Turns out the issue wasn't on the code. Problem was somehow on the github oauth2 credentials. When I used a token/secret generated by [Google Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?pli=1) I didn't have to change anything else besides the application.properties.

The mistery about github login still remains, since there's not much data on the token register to be changed.